# CSS - header to stay in top of container

Tags: html, css

I have this container which can scroll the content. I would like the header in this container to always stay in the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/z9ze5/

Container:

```
.lists {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;  
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #39C;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
}
```

Header:

```
.box_header {
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    background: #DDD;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to alter your mark-up, here is one way of doing it:

```
<div class="lists">
    <header class="box_header">
        <h1>HEADER 2</h1>
        <div class="setting" id="btn2"></div>
    </header>
    <section class="content">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum ....</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Wrap your scroll area in a `<section>` (or other block level element).

For your CSS:

```
.lists {
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
margin: 30px auto;
background: #39C;
position: relative;
}
section.content {
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #39C;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/nGGXx/

**More Advanced Example**

If you study the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/fBNTP/

uou can see how your scrolling boxes could be applied in a semi-flexible layout.
I lined up two scrolling boxes side by side and made their width proportionate to the width of the page.

The height is trickier to adjust.  I fixed the height of the parent container, see the following rule:

```
.contentWrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 1.00em;
    padding: 30px 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
```

If you change the height from 400px to some other value, the scrolling boxes will adjust themselves.

Hopefully, these examples will give you and others some more insights into how to build these more advanced layout designs.

Comment: And what if

`section.content {...}
`
needs to be flexible with ex. `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;`

How would this be done?

Comment: In general, flexible width is relatively easy: in `section.container` you can set `width: 100%` and it will inherit the width based on the parent container `.lists`.  The height is a bit trickier; it depends on the height of `.lists`, will this be fixed? how will it be used in the page layout?  If you can provide more details of your design, we can probably help you more specifically.

Comment: Your example still has an issue. When you press the blue button the content, slides down with it.

I have made this fiddle to show what it is I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/DWL5C/

Right now the scroll works as I wan't it, but when you change y-height in `<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="3" data-sizey="2">` to ex. 3 instead of 2 the content doesn't follow

Hope I explained it okay?

Comment: I see what you mean.  I altered how the header is set up to get around another issue to keep the vertical height flexible.  I will take a look at it.

Comment: I fixed the issue, the header now has the toggle slide effect.

Comment: Cool your fiddle work the way I wan't – I will try adding this to my fiddle and see if this works. ––– I will keep you updated ----- Thank for taking your time helping me!!!

Comment: Please remember to accept and up vote the answer.  You are working on a fairly advanced design especially with the drag-drop plug in.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to your fix, i Think I Foundation an okay solution... I Will post a fiddle tomorrow, with the updated version... Thanks you again

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non-css fix, add this listener...

```
$('.lists').scroll(function() {
    $('.box_header', this).css('top', $(this).scrollTop()+'px');
});
```

and then change .lists css to give relative positioning

```
.box_header {
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    background: #DDD;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: if you change the position to relative in the css for the `.box_header` the text-content will slide down with the header when you push the blue button and if is set to `position: absolute;` the header "jumps" when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Any position absolute within a position relative is absolute to the relative container. In order to have a header that stays in position, you'd need to position it above, not within, the scrolling container.

Answer (score 0):

look at adding position: fixed to your header div .box_header. You may have to add padding of the height of the box header div to section.content but as you have that set to 30px that should be fine. IE6 and lower has issues with fixed positioning but hopefully we can live with that now - less people are using that than are still listening to Moby.